# How to decrypt binary string in React Native?

Tags: react-native, debugging, encryption, electron, cryptography

**Bellow we have an encrypted hex string data. Test is done in React Native and Electron. Both RN and Electron have the same IV and the same KEY and the base64 of hexEnryptedData is the same on both platforms.**

The Electron version does it works because that decrypted data is a png image 1x1 pixels and can be rendered in a  tag.

But, in React Native... I see that is a problem with decryption. If you are looking at numbers, it seems that is a problem with padding and some other numbers inside.

This problem is just on binary string because deconding strings like "Hello World!" and JSON does works perfect!

---

```
var key = '902e80631a967943289d73274a544de26b856c288b4e60b71004424a7426bdd3';

var iv = 'a9fd946e7f732703dd5e30e8d82aeed3';

var hexEncryptedData = '29f3cade12b11184f6c65307af46290c191915487d63b7d8e1a11a4643553636871ad9324ba66a9ec5f0797f2fdbe4d7374734cad06b0ac79073bc476690b913d143d34626bb75e943598de86c9f01f515ca4dd6becbd85cfe3b94ebea44219f0f64921657952d8ee4ce2d824ac4476bd50598f0a9b3f9321e71a9471a7c05aa'
```

---

**React Native**:

```
import Aes from 'react-native-aes-crypto'; 
base64EncryptedData = Buffer.from(hexEncryptedData, 'hex').toString('base64'); 
var data = await Aes.decrypt(base64EncryptedData, key, iv, 'aes-256-cbc');
```

Resulted Uint8Array in Debug Mode: [253,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,8,6,0,0,0,31,21,9,0,0,0,1,115,82,71,66,0,253,253,28,253,0,0,0,4,103,65,77,65,0,0,253,253,11,253,97,5,0,0,0,9,112,72,89,115,0,0,14,253,0,0,14,253,1,21,40,74,253,0,0,0,13,73,68,65,84,24,87,99,120,43,253,253,31,0,5,84,2,45,253,61,253,253,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,253,66,96,253]

Resulted Buffer if is not in Debug Mode: [253, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10]

---

**React Native** another try

```
var aesjs = require('aes-js');
var encryptedBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(hexEncryptedData);
var aesCbc = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.cbc(Buffer.from(key, 'hex'), Buffer.from(iv, 'hex'));
var decryptedBytes = aesCbc.decrypt(encryptedBytes);
```

Resulted Uint8Array: [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 31, 21, 196, 137, 0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 82, 71, 66, 0, 174, 206, 28, 233, 0, 0, 0, 4, 103, 65, 77, 65, 0, 0, 177, 143, 11, 252, 97, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 112, 72, 89, 115, 0, 0, 14, 194, 0, 0, 14, 194, 1, 21, 40, 74, 128, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 68, 65, 84, 24, 87, 99, 120, 43, 163, 242, 31, 0, 5, 84, 2, 45, 198, 61, 146, 157, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]

> the problem is the padding at the end, in rest the output is the same as the Electron version ^_^

**Electron**:

```
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
var decryptedData = decipher.update(hexEncryptedData, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
```

Resulted Uint8Array: [137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,8,6,0,0,0,31,21,196,137,0,0,0,1,115,82,71,66,0,174,206,28,233,0,0,0,4,103,65,77,65,0,0,177,143,11,252,97,5,0,0,0,9,112,72,89,115,0,0,14,194,0,0,14,194,1,21,40,74,128,0,0,0,13,73,68,65,84,24,87,99,120,43,163,242,31,0,5,84,2,45,198,61,146,157,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,174,66,96,130]

---

The Electron resulted decryption is correct, it works. Why the React Native seems to be broken?

Also, if I use window.crypto.subtle.decrypt in React Native in Debug mode, it decrypts correct. But, this does not exist if Debug Mode is not actived.

Comment: Without key and IV, the problem is not reproducible. Post complete, non-productive test data: key, IV, plaintext, ciphertext. Also, it is strange that the Uint8Array 137, 80,... to the UTF-8 decoded string decryptedData contains non-UTF-8 compatible byte sequences. How do you create this Uint8Array from decryptedData? Post the full code so that a repro is possible.

Comment: By the way, this is obviously a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171887/react-native-does-not-decrypt-correct-binary-data, so you should delete one of the two posts.

Comment: @Topaco it doesn't matter where the text to be decrypted is from. That hexEncryptedData is generated by Electron and is valid and it is working in NodeJS, Electron, Google Chrome. In that enviroments the decryption is perfect and that image is loaded without problems. The Electron output is the correct so we need a solution for React Native to generate the same output. OK, a duplicate but they have different perspectives.

Comment: Possibly the problem lies in the fact that, as a string, the value 26 that follows your shortened ciphertext is the SUB character, which may be interpreted as EOF.

Comment: *... it doesn't matter where the text to be decrypted is from. That hexEncryptedData is generated by Electron and is valid ...* Yes, it is relevant for the troubleshooting. Why should I rely on the data being correct? After all, the posted code is also wrong, because it can't possibly have generated the posted data. But that can only be verified with test data, which is why it is important.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd attempt with *aes-js*: This library does not seem to pad/unpad, s. [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-js#cbc---cipher-block-chaining-recommended). The last 8 bytes are therefore most likely PKCS#7 padding bytes, which you have to remove explicitly when using this library. There are libraries for this, but you can also do it yourself: In [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) each padding byte specifies the number of padding bytes, in the posted example 8, which have to be removed.

Comment: Regarding your 1st attempt with *react-native-aes-crypto*: This library seems to implicitly UTF-8 decode on decryption, s. [here](https://github.com/tectiv3/react-native-aes/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/tectiv3/aes/RCTAes.java#L225). Arbitrary binary data (as opposed to data resulting from UTF-8 encoding) is corrupted by UTF-8, which is (most likley) the cause of the problem (which, by the way, is also the reason why the code posted in the Electron part cannot generate the data posted there, s [here](http://www.jdoodle.com/ia/HtA)).

Comment: Yeah, maybe I pasted wrong at Electron section, but your output test shows my output. That format with CBC I‘ve used in the last 8 years and it works on Java, NodeJS, Electron, Xamarin (C#) and others without problems on decrypting/encrypting strings and binary files. In React Native all libraries that I‘ve tried, just problems.

In conclusion, 'react-native-aes-crypto' cannot be used for binary (files) and 'aes-js' works but if padding is removed every time?

Comment: The test shows that in the Electron part the posted data is correct and that the posted code does not work. The problem in the code is not the AES/CBC encryption/decryption, but the UTF-8 decoding. aes-js works, but the decrypted data must be explicitly unpadded. react-native-aes-crypto does not work for arbitrary binary data. The reason is the same as for your code (namely the UTF-8 decoding).